# Accessing Jupyter notebook widgets values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

While trying to use the Jupyter widgets to control a different function I am stumbling over this issue and am searching for a workaround.

The widget is displayed and I can interact with it just fine. Reading the value, as stated in the documentation using `w.value` also works. But now reading the value continuously in a loop does not work. Whereas I uncheck the box the value in the while loop never changes.

How can I control python functions via the widgets if they are not updated with the current state of the widgets?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. My reference is this [link](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html).

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    return 'value of checkbox is: ' + str(x)

w = widgets.Checkbox(value=True, description='Updated?')
interact(f,x=w)
```

Comment: The `interact` function works nicely to adjust parameters for functions that calculate a value. In my case though I have a basically infinite loop that should be aborted when a button is pressed. At the moment I can't think how to make that work with `interact` because I need to query the current state.

Comment: To abort something that is running in my jupyter notebook, I simply use the stop button (interrupt kernel) OR CTRL + C.